# Using two combo boxes to determine value for a textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Am fairly new to the world of MS Access and struggling to get my head around this.

I have a form designed to help updating content on a website. I'm trying to work out how to populate fields with entries from past dates.

I have set up two combo boxes for each 'spot' on the site, one for date: **Feature_1_Date** and one for which content spot the content was occupying **Feature_1_Spot**.

The idea being that these boxes would read the row from my table to find the date, and the column to find which spot the content did occupy to copy the same content into a field **Feature_1_Content**

From what I can gether I need to use DLOOKUP (I'm very familiar with VLOOKUP on excel) but I'm doing something very wrong as can't get it to show any content.

So far I have this:

```
Me.Feature_1_Content = DLookup("[FEATURE_1_Spot]", "tb_website", "[Feature_1_Spot]")
```

Grateful for any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: It would help immensely if you could edit your post to show exactly what your code looks like.  It's possible there is just one small typo that we could easily fix.  Without that, we're kind of shooting at a wall and you probably won't get anyone to waste time helping you.

Comment: Good point, edit made!

Answer (score 0):

Your DLookUp statement basically says, "I want what's in field Feature_1_Spot, from table tb_website, where Feature_1_Spot."  Access has no idea what you're actually looking for.  The 1st requirement is the field you want to return, the 2nd requirement is the table you're searching, and the 3rd requirement should be the "WHERE" clause.  I'm thinking it will probably look something more like this:

```
Me.Feature_1_Content = DLookup("[FEATURE_1_Content]", "tb_website", "[Feature_1_Spot] = '" & Me!Feature_1_Spot.text & '" AND [Feature_1_Date] = #" & Me!Feature_1_Date.text & "#")
```

You may have to tweak that a bit, but it should be really close.